# Question about the investment calculator interest rate

Tags: interest

I have a quick question question about this investment calculator.
It is the website calculator.net/investment calculator
Basically I put in my starting amount of investment is 4800, for 1 year, with a return rate of 10%, compounded annually.
And I add a contribution of 100 dollar at the beggining of the month

So I did my calculation I did

$(4800+100)*(.10/12))$ to get my interest amount of $40.833$

But the calculator says the correct amount of interest is 39.07

I am confused how they get 39.07 for the interest amount. I though if it is 10 compound interest you do .10/12 to get monthly interest. please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interest rate used in the calculator is the [effective annual rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation) or, equivalently, the nominal annual rate compounded *annually*.  To work out the monthly rate `mr` you have to invert the compounding like so:

```
ar = 0.10

mr = (1 + ar)^(1/12) - 1 = 0.00797414

(4800 + 100) * mr = 39.0733
```

If the interest rate was a nominal annual rate compounded *monthly* the monthly rate would be calculated as `mr = ar/12`.  Then the effective annual rate would be `(1 + mr)^12 - 1 = 0.104713`

Nominal rates are created as multiples of their compounding period to make calculations easier, e.g. `mr = ar/12`.  The cost is that, say a 10% nominal annual rate compounded monthly, weekly, or daily all result in different interest accruals over a year.

Comment: I have a quick question so what is ar, is it the annual rate

Comment: @FernandoMartinez Yes, annual rate (effective or nominal according to context).